# How to restrict a view by

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, associations

I have successfully set up a friendship self referencial association for users in my Ruby on Rails app after following [Ryan Bates' railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association). I can successfully follow, unfollow, and view who is following. Now I want to pull in another element and I am not sure how to do it.

When visiting a user/show page of a user that the `current_user` is already `friends` with...what is the syntax for checking the `Friendships` table for an existing friendship.

Here is how the associations are set up.

Friendship.rb

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :friend, :class_name => "User"
```

User.rb

```
  has_many :friendships
  has_many :friends, :through => :friendships
  has_many :inverse_friendships, :class_name => "Friendship", :foreign_key => "friend_id"
  has_many :inverse_friends, :through => :inverse_friendships, :source => :user

  def friends_workouts
    @friends_workouts ||= Workout.find_all_by_user_id(self.friends.map(&:id), :order => "created_at DESC", :limit => 3)
  end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd go with something like this:

```
def friends_with?(other_user)
  friends.include?(other_user) || inverse_friends.include?(other_user)
end
```

Comment: So I dropped that in the model but what is the view syntax? <% if current_user.friends_with? %> doesn't work.

Comment: Nevermind...I figured it out. <% unless current_user.friends_with?(@user) %>

Comment: BTW, I just asked a follow up question that you may be interested in answering. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242170/how-to-reference-the-my-friendships-table-to-conditionally-display-code

Comment: Actually, this has a slight problem in that if a user a follows user b, then when user b goes to user a's profile, the logic doesn't display the follow link (using unless).

Comment: figured it out again, just had to drop the second half of your statement.